# Como sumar datos de una columna en Datatables

Tags: datatables

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde necesito sumar los valos de una columna cuando se cumpla la condicion que el pago fue completado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado con esto pero me suma todos los valores de la columna precio:

```
"drawCallback": function (){
                var api = this.api();
                var suma_usd = Number(api.column(8).data().sum().toFixed(2));
               
                $('#total-usd').text(suma_usd);
                 },
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Vale, tengo esta tabla que tiene varios columnas, quisiea que cuando en la columna Pagada el valor sea 1, se haga una suma de los valosres de la columna Precio para esa condicion.

Comment: Y qué es lo que has probado? Qué has investigado?

Comment: He probado con drawCallback y sum(), pero esto me hace una sumatoria de todos los valores de la columna sin importar si se pagó o no

Comment: Te importaría compartir lo que has probado en la pregunta, como ser codigo, documentación y todo. Por favor, edita tu pregunta.